# How to install npm when node has been compiled with prefix

Tags: node.js, compilation, npm

I have installed node from source using the git repository. The current path of node is
/Users/toutpt/makina/cubes/parts/nodejs/bin/node

Now I get the source of npm and I can't specify at install tho use this node. Every google results point me out to link it from /usr/bin/node or to add /Users/toutpt/makina/cubes/parts/nodejs/bin as part of global PATH

All my try give me the same error:
bin/npm: line 5: node: command not found

I don't want and I can't make it global on my system because of system restriction. I would like to have each project use it's own version of node so of NPM.

I want to use npm by using it's path:
/Users/toutpt/makina/cubes/parts/npm/bin/npm install ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your use-case is:

> I would like to have each project use it's own version of node so of NPM

Maybe a [node version management software](http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2013/03/23/installing-and-switching-between-multiple-versions-of-node-js-n-vs-nvm/) ala **n** (https://github.com/visionmedia/n) or **nvm** (github.com/creationix/nvm) would be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its help but I would do this:
go to the path you mentioned then

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: IN this script you will find # make sure that node exists
node=`which node 2>&1` which mean npm wait for a global node command on the system.